# Button are not working in javascript discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

today I just tried to do an suggestion system, and buttons in that are not working, there are the codes
suggest.js

```
const { ChatInputCommandInteraction, ModalBuilder, TextInputStyle, TextInputBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');
const GuildConfiguration = require('../models/GuildConfiguration');
const Suggestion = require('../models/Suggestion');
const formatResults = require('../utils/formatResults');


module.exports = {
    data: {
        name:'suggest',
        description: 'Создайте идею.',
        dm_permission: false,
    },

    /**
     * 
     * @param {Object} param0 
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} param0.interaction 
     */
    run: async ({ interaction }) => {
        try {
            const guildConfiguration = await GuildConfiguration.findOne({ guildId: interaction.guildId });

            if (!guildConfiguration?.suggestionChannelIds.length) {
                await interaction.reply(
                    'Данный сервер пока ещё не настроен для заявок.\nОбратитесь к администратору и попросите его написать команду `/config-suggestions add`, чтобы настроить данный сервер.'
                );
                return;
            }
    
            if (!guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds.includes(interaction.channelId)) {
                await interaction.reply(
                    `Этот канал не настроен для идей.\nПопробуйте использовать один из данных каналов: ${guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds
                    .map((id) => `<#${id}>`)
                    .join(', ')}`
                )
            }
    
            const modal = new ModalBuilder()
                .setTitle('Создайте идею')
                .setCustomId(`suggestion-${interaction.user.id}`);
    
            const textInput = new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('suggestion-input')
                .setLabel('Что вы хотите предложить?')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
                .setRequired(true)
                .setMaxLength(1000);
    
            const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(textInput);

            modal.addComponents(actionRow);
    
            await interaction.showModal(modal);
    
            const filter = (i) => i.customId === `suggestion-${interaction.user.id}`;
    
            const modalInteraction = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
                filter,
                time: 1000 * 60 * 3
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    
            await modalInteraction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
    
            let suggestionMessage;
    
            try {
                suggestionMessage = await interaction.channel.send('Создаю идею, пожалуйста подождите...')
            } catch (error) {
                modalInteraction.editReply(
                    'У меня не получилось создать идею в этом канале. Возможно, у меня недостаточно прав.'
                );
                return;
            }
    
            const suggestionText = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('suggestion-input');
    
            const newSuggestion = new Suggestion({
                authorId: interaction.user.id,
                guildId: interaction.guildId,
                messageId: suggestionMessage.id,
                content: suggestionText,
            })
    
            await newSuggestion.save();
    
            modalInteraction.editReply('Идея успешно создалась!');
    
            // SuggestionEmbed
            const suggestionEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setAuthor({
                    name: interaction.user.username,
                    iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 256 }),
                })
                .addFields([
                    { name: 'Идея', value: suggestionText },
                    { name: 'Статус', value: '⌛ Ожидает ответа' },
                    { name: 'Голоса:', value: formatResults() },
                ])
                .setColor('Yellow');
    
            //buttons
            const upvoteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setEmoji('')
                .setLabel('Нравится')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                .setCustomId(`suggestion.${newSuggestion.suggestionId}.upvote`);
    
            const downvoteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setEmoji('')
                .setLabel('Не нравится')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                .setCustomId(`suggestion.${newSuggestion.suggestionId}.downvote`);
            
            const approveButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setEmoji('✅')
                .setLabel('Одобрить')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                .setCustomId(`suggestion.${newSuggestion.suggestionId}.approve`)
    
            const rejectButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setEmoji('️')
                .setLabel('Отклонить')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                .setCustomId(`suggestion.${newSuggestion.suggestionId}.reject`)
    
            //rows
            const firstRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(upvoteButton, downvoteButton);
            const secondRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(approveButton, rejectButton);
    
            suggestionMessage.edit({
                content: `${interaction.user} Идея создана!`,
                embeds: [suggestionEmbed],
                components: [firstRow, secondRow],
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
};
```

handleSuggestions.js

```
const { Interaction } = require('discord.js');
const Suggestion = require('../../models/Suggestion');

/**
 * 
 * @param {Interaction} interaction 
 */
module.exports = async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton() || !interaction.customId) return;

    try {
        const [type, suggestionId, action] = interaction.customId.split('.');

        if (!type || !suggestionId || !action) return;
        if (type !== 'suggestion') return;


        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

        const targetSuggestion = await Suggestion.findOne({ suggestionId });
        const targetMessage = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch(targetSuggestion.messageId);
        const targetMessageEmbed = targetMessage.embeds[0];

        if (action === 'approve') {
            if (!interaction.memberPermissions.has('Administrator')) {
                await interaction.editReply('У вас недостаточно прав, чтобы одобрить идею.');
                return;
            }

            targetSuggestion.status = 'approved';

            targetMessageEmbed.data.color = 0x84e660
            targetMessageEmbed.fields[1].value = '✅ Одобрено'

            await targetSuggestion.save();

            interaction.editReply('Заявка одобрена!');

            targetMessage.edit({
                embeds: [targetMessageEmbed],
                components: [targetMessage.components[0]],
            });

            return;
        }

        if (action === 'approve') {
            if (!interaction.memberPermissions.has('Administrator')) {
                await interaction.editReply('У вас недостаточно прав, чтобы отклонить идею.');
                return;
            }

            targetSuggestion.status = 'rejected';

            targetMessageEmbed.data.color = 0xff6161;
            targetMessageEmbed.fields[1].value = '❌ Отклонено';

            await targetSuggestion.save();

            interaction.editReply('Заявка отклонена!');

            targetMessage.edit({
                embeds: [targetMessageEmbed],
                components: [targetMessage.components[0]],
            });

            return;
        }    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error in handleSuggestion.js: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

Suggestion.js

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const {randomUUID} = require('crypto');

const suggestionSchema = new Schema({
    suggestionId: {
        type: String,
        default: randomUUID,
    },
    authorId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    guildId: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
    },
    messageId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        // "Ожидает ответа", "Принято", "Отклонено"
        default: "Ожидает ответа",
    },
    upvotes: {
        type: [String],
        default: [],
    },
    downvotes: {
        type: [String],
        default: [],
    },
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = model('Suggestion', suggestionSchema);
```

GuildConfiguration.js

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const guildConfigurationSchema = new Schema({
    guildId: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    suggestionChannelIds: {
        type: [String],
        default: [],
    },
});

module.exports = model('GuildConfiguration', guildConfigurationSchema);
```

config-suggestions.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, ChatInputCommandInteraction } = require('discord.js');
const GuildConfiguration = require('../models/GuildConfiguration');

module.exports = {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Object} param0 
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} param0.interaction 
     */
    run: async ({ interaction }) => {
        let guildConfiguration = await GuildConfiguration.findOne({ guildId: interaction.guildId });

        if (!guildConfiguration) {
            guildConfiguration = new GuildConfiguration({ guildId: interaction.guildId });
        };

        const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();

        if (subcommand === 'add') {
            const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');

            if (guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds.includes(channel.id)) {
                await interaction.reply(`${channel} уже является каналом для идей.`);
                return;
            };

            guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds.push(channel.id);
            await guildConfiguration.save();

            await interaction.reply(`${channel} стал каналом для идей.`);
            return;
        };

        if (subcommand === 'remove') {
            const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');
            if (!guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds.includes(channel.id)) {
                await interaction.reply(`${channel} не является каналом для идей.`);
                return;
            };

            guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds = guildConfiguration.suggestionChannelIds.filter(
                (id) => id !== channel.id
            );
            await guildConfiguration.save();

            await interaction.reply(`Канал ${channel} перестал быть каналом для идей.`);
            return;
        };
    },

    options: {
        userPermissions: ['Administrator']
    },

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('config-suggestions')
        .setDescription('Изменяйте настройки канала идей.')
        .setDMPermission(false)
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
         subcommand
            .setName('add')
            .setDescription('Добавьте канал с идеями.')
            .addChannelOption((option) => 
            option
                .setName('channel')
                .setDescription('Канал, который Вы хотите добавить.')
                .addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
                .setRequired(true)
            ),
        )
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
        subcommand
           .setName('remove')
           .setDescription('Уберите канал с идеями.')
           .addChannelOption((option) => 
           option
               .setName('channel')
               .setDescription('Канал, который Вы хотите убрать.')
               .addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
               .setRequired(true)
           ),
       ),
    
};
```

and formatResults.js

```
const pb = {
    le: '<:_le:1166350863485382687>',
    me: '<:_me:1166350862252257290>',
    re: '<:_re:1166350860947837030>',
    lf: '<:_lf:1166350857986637875>',
    mf: '<:_mf:1166350856346669117>',
    rf: '<:_rf:1166350853158993980>',
  };
  
  function formatResults(upvotes = [], downvotes = []) {
    const totalVotes = upvotes.length + downvotes.length;
    const progressBarLength = 14;
    const filledSquares = Math.round((upvotes.length / totalVotes) * progressBarLength) || 0;
    const emptySquares = progressBarLength - filledSquares || 0;
  
    if (!filledSquares && !emptySquares) {
      emptySquares = progressBarLength;
    }
  
    const upPercentage = (upvotes.length / totalVotes) * 100 || 0;
    const downPercentage = (downvotes.length / totalVotes) * 100 || 0;
  
    const progressBar =
      (filledSquares ? pb.lf : pb.le) +
      (pb.mf.repeat(filledSquares) + pb.me.repeat(emptySquares)) +
      (filledSquares === progressBarLength ? pb.rf : pb.re);
  
    const results = [];
    results.push(
      ` ${upvotes.length} upvotes (${upPercentage.toFixed(1)}%) •  ${
        downvotes.length
      } downvotes (${downPercentage.toFixed(1)}%)`
    );
    results.push(progressBar);
  
    return results.join('\n');
  }
  
  module.exports = formatResults;
```

I'm just trying to click on buttons, and them are not working. Thank you in advance if you will help!

Comment: What behavior is expected from the buttons?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please try to provide a [**Minimum** Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It's great that you provided all of your code, as opposed to not enough, but every line you can remove while still showing the problem will make it easier for us to look at and in fact easier for you to debug. Thanks!